# Google Street View Embedded iFrame Focus Jump

Tags: ios, google-maps, iframe, google-street-view

My Google Street View iFrame loads fine but when I touch inside the image of the Street View map the page jumps to the bottom. This only happens on my Iphone 5s as well as my IPAD.

If I click on one of the controls it does not jump - but as soon as I touch the screen as if I want to drag the view to look around the page jumps to the bottom.

This happens on two of my websites where I have embedded the Street View Iframe so it cannot be specific to the website.

Can anyone advise how to prevent this annoying jump?

My website is http://www.360tours.co.za

Comment: Seems it is working on your site :) Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It seems to be related to iOS 10. Testing on the ipad3 with iOS 9.3.5 it works fine. Embedding it in a simple html page with only the iframe it seems to work fine. Looks like a combination of certain things.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using this trick:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
```

Something to note - if you have absolutely positioned elements which are direct children of body (e.g. header), this will cause other issues on iOS - so you would need to wrap the site in a relatively positioned container.

Answer (score 0):

adding this code

```
   `body, html {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
    } `
```

caused dissapearing CSS animation in IOS on my site. May be due to "if you have absolutely positioned elements which are direct children of body"

didnt catch how to solve this issue so i just removed overflow and everything works fine now
nevertheless Thanks